# How can I set up two-way or three-way trades in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

How can I use a Google Sheets formula to set up trades between different users?

I had a bunch of people participating in a random draw. In this Google Sheet they recorded the option they wanted and the option they actually got. I want to find a way to not only find perfect matches (Where userA and userB can be matched and trade for what they want) but situations where 3+ users could make a three-way trade and so on.

Here's the example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KU4dWMbTqAcexwhJKAyuVvQgjRPVYCYoJf4T4aOgyV8/edit?usp=sharing

I'm able to do the first match using:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,B2:C50,2,false)
```

but I can't get three-way or more matches.

I would like a concatenated list of the one, two, or three people you have to trade within Column D.

Comment: I should also mention, I am only getting one way matches, when I need what people want to also match what the other person got!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in D2 and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({B$2:C}, "select Col2 where Col1 = '"&A2&"'", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

if you want no more than 3 use:

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({B$2:C}, "select Col2 where Col1 = '"&A2&"' limit 3", 0)))
```